# Find and replace white spaces in html

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to find and replace all white spaces in a html file. Here's my code so far:

```
html.replace(@ (?![^<]*>|[^<>]*</)@g,"&nbsp;")
```

But above expression throws error as not a valid expression. How do I make it work?

Comment: Use `/` to delimit regex literals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regexes are delimited by `/`, not `@`.

```
html.replace(/ (?![^<]*>|[^<>]*<\/)/g,"&nbsp;")
```

Here's another regex that literally replaces every white space with a non-breaking space:

```
html.replace(/\s+/g, "&nbsp;");
```

Comment: I see. I tought it works as same as php do. And how about expression. Still its not converts white spaces into the &nbsp ?

Comment: @TeomanTıngır Did you re-add the space that Jack inadvertently removed? I just edited it back in. Also, do you assign the result of `replace()` to a variable? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Whoops, sorry @melpomene.

Comment: @melpomene yes I did. I also kinda forgot to mentioned that I dont want to remove white spaces inside of the html tags. Because if there are tag attributes, it breaks html and makes it unreadable.